# How to implement href attribute to pass different company's website links to redirect on that?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring-mvc, jsp

I want to implement in my JSP, that when admin clicks on added company's website so he/she should be able to redirect to that particular company's official website. I have generated dynamic table row and used anchor tag. But I have no idea about how to pass different links dynamically.

```
function tabledataajax(limit){
            var selectedtab = document.getElementById('selectedtab').value;
            var url = "../<%=AkApiUrl.getusertable%>";
            $.post(url,{ 
                limit:limit,
                companystatus : selectedtab,
            }, function(data, status) { 
                if (data.status == "OK") { 
                    if (data.statusCode == 1) {
                        var row = "";  //Variable to hold html tag 
                        var list = data.response;
                        var listlength = list.length;
                        if(listlength > 0){
                            for( var i = 0; i < listlength; i++){
                                  row = row+"<tr id='tr"+list[i].userid+"' onclick=\"selectedrow('"+list[i].userid+"');\">"+"<td>"+list[i].company+"</td><td>"+list[i].companystatus+"</td><td>"+list[i].phone+"</td>"+"<td>"+list[i].address+"</td><td>"+list[i].landline+"</td><td><a href='#'>"+list[i].website+"</a></td><td><button onclick=\"edituser('"+list[i].userid+"');\">Edit</button></td></tr>";
                            }
                        }else{
                            row = "<tr><td colspan = 6>No Record Found.</td></tr>";
                        }
                        document.getElementById('customerlistwithpagination').innerHTML = row;
                } else {
                         var error = data.responseMessage;
                        swal(error, "", "error");
                    }
                } else {
                         var error = data.responseMessage;
                        swal(error, "", "error");
                }
            });
```

Comment: you need to do that onclick of `a` tag? if yes why not give value to `href="toredirectlink"` ?

Comment: If I do so, then, I would be able to redirect to one link which would be static. Suppose, I have 10 companies in my database and each of them have different domain name. So, I want to redirect to their URLs from my view (i.e. JSP page).

Comment: is this `list[i].website` link ?

Comment: Yes, I have lists of websites for different company.

Comment: then use that value inside href attribute i.e : `href="+list[i].website+"`

Comment: It worked. Thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228339/discussion-between-rakhi-sharma-and-swati).